# Операции над данными в MySQL при добавлении строки с использованием Entity Framework Core

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core, форматирование

Одно из требований заказчика заключается в том, чтобы при выставлении счетов на оплату, счёт был в формате ХХ 000 000 000, где ХХ - некоторый код, который указывает на информацию о клиенте (задумка в том, что только взглянув на счёт, можно было определить, в какой категории клиентов находится владелец счёта), а нули - просто число, получаемое авто-инкрементом. И вот встаёт вопрос о том, как это реализовать:

Программа пишется на asp.net core, БД MySQL, для общения с БД используется entity framework core.

То, как я это пока представляю, немного попахивает костылями:
Сделать 2 поля: `InvoiceId` и `InvoiceNumber`;
Счёт создавать так, что сначала заполнить сам счёт;
затем добавить его в БД;
получить авто-инкремент для `InvoiceId`;
заполнить `InvoiceNumber`, добавив к `InvoiceId` в начало ХХ;
и затем записать изменения в БД.

Главная проблема, какую я тут вижу - в БД придётся дважды делать `SaveChanges()` - 1 раз для получения `InvoiceId`, и второй для записи `InvoiceNumber`.

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ не совершать дополнительное обращение к БД? Быть может, можно это форматирование возложить на плечи самой MySQL?

Comment: Хмм, вы подумывали о использовании виртуального столбца? Храните XX и id(который, важно, auto_increment) в отдельных столбцах. Добавьте виртуальный столбец, равный XX * 1 000 000 000 + id. Виртуальный столбец не материален, поэтому вам достаточно лишь хранить в базе данных двухзначное и 9-тизначное числа.

Comment: Просто храните в БД эти два значения. А склейку в одно значение делайте в клиентском коде.